# Wait until method is executed inside backgroundworker c#

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I am really new to programming and I have very less knowledge. I am currently in a bad situation. I have a `BackGroundWorker` and a `Mehod`. I am calling the method from the `DoWork` event of the `BackGroundWorker`. The problem  is, the `RunWorkerCompleted` event is being fired before the method is done executing :

```
string[] files;
private void BGW1_DoWorkAsync(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
    populate();
}

private void populate() {
    files = GetFiles(@"C:\filesystem"); ///100 files here
}

private void BGW1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) {
    foreach(string filename in files) {

    }
}
```

In the loop inside the `RunWorkerCompleted` event, I sometimes get errors like `Collection was modified` and sometimes it returns filenames but not all of them(maybe because `populate` method didn't finish entirely ?)

So, is there a way to wait until the method has been executed entirely/fully ? I have heard about Async/Await but I have no idea how to use it in my specific case. Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Did you try to use `AutoResetEvent` event?

Comment: @Saadi , i am totally new, can you atleast share a link please?

Comment: I've shared a sample example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `AutoResetEvent` event along with `BackgroundWorker`.

```
class Program
{
    private static BackgroundWorker worker = new System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker();
    private static AutoResetEvent resetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    private string[] files;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
        worker.ProgressChanged += worker_ProgressChanged;
        worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

        Console.WriteLine("Starting Application...");

        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        resetEvent.WaitOne();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ProgressPercentage.ToString());
    }

    static void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        files = GetFiles(@"C:\filesystem"); ///100 files here

        resetEvent.Set();
    }

    static void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach(string filename in files) {

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: i will try it in a minute

Comment: Ok. try it and let me know what is the result. Thanks!

Comment: This will not work ... i am sorry .... I need the code : `files =...` to be in a method :(

Comment: Did you try to put in a method?

Comment: sorry for such a late reply, it worked ..i was busy for these days so i couldn't come back !